# Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Express Edition connect with svn

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express

how can I connect with svn server in Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Express Edition. I've tried install tortoiseSVN and ankhSVN, but I read Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Express Edition doesn't support plugins.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title. As written, it merely duplicates information you've provided in your tags. A title should clearly describe the specific problem you're having or ask a specific question, in a manner that will be of use to someone who sees it in a search result in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) instead.  It's free and supports plugins like ankhSVN.

Comment: Can I create commercial project in Community version ?

Comment: You can create "for-sale" projects, though there are some limitations on the size of your company.  The Q&A section on the linked page addresses that.

Comment: Like AnkhSVN or VisualSVN or any other plug-in actually.